# How to get the replication status of azure blob

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to find out if my blobs have been replicated using the Azure portal. I have selected RA-GRS for redundancy. I found out a class which provides the api to fetch replication status **azure::storage::service_stats::geo_replication_stats** class. Is there a way to check the status using Azure portal?

Comment: This is something not exposed in the portal (aside from whether primary and secondary regions are available, and when the last failover took place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of today, it is not possible to view the status in the portal.

As a workaround, you can use code or api:

1. You may use code which is mentioned in the below link and this should help you in checking the status:
   https://gist.github.com/ajith-k/92867fb6e5329ff9300d712df12f2809
2. You can also refer to the REST API calls - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-service-stats